# How does the cache coherency protocol enforce atomicity?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, cpu, atomic

I understand atomicity can be guaranteed on operations like `xsub()`, without using the `LOCK` prefix, by relying on the cache coherency protocol (MESI/MESIF).

1) How can the cache coherency protocol do this???

Its making me wonder if the cache coherency protocol can enforce atomicity, why do we need special atomic types/instructions etc?

2) If MOSI implements atomic instructions across multi-core systems then what is the purpose of `LOCK`? Legacy?

3) If MOSI implements atomic instructions and MOSI is used for all instructions- then why do atomic instructions cost so much? Surely the performance should be same as normal instructions.

Comment: Special atomic types are there to ensure compiler generates single instructions and doesn't do any reordering itself. The `LOCK` prefix serializes the instruction on the CPU ensuring it doesn't happen out order with respect to other instructions. The `LOCK` prefix also guarantees atomicity on non-cached accesses (or at least asks for it by asserting LOCK#) I don't know how specifically the cache maintains coherency, but it effectively needs to do it's own locking on any memory access to maintain that coherency. That means you get weakly ordered atomic accesses essentially for free.

Comment: My confusion gets worse- I have read that on single-CPU systems you basically don't need LOCK, thats more for multi-processor systems. MESIF controls atomicity on a single-CPU system??

Comment: On single CPU systems there's no cache coherency needed as there are no other CPUs to observe whether accesses through the cache are atomic or not. When accessing memory locations shared with devices, both on single CPU and multi CPU systems, you need to disable the cache in the shared address space. Cache coherency is only maintained between CPU caches and externally most accesses through the caches will appear as reads and writes of entire 64 byte long cache lines. The LOCK prefix is needed for read/modify/write instructions to appear to be atomic to devices.

Comment: The confusion comes from there being two uses of "atomic": atomic with respect to interrupts (i.e., single thread at a time) and atomic with respect to multiple concurrent threads. From the perspective of a single thread, it loads a value, performs the operation on the loaded value and stores the result. An interrupt will occur semantically either before the load or after the store. However, with concurrent threads, one thread could load 4, add 1, and store 5 while the other thread also loads 4, adds 1, and stores 5.

Comment: related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `xsub` instruction in x86, but there is an `xadd` ;)

You should read the section about the `LOCK` prefix in the *Instruction Set Reference*, and the section *8.1 LOCKED ATOMIC OPERATIONS* in the *Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1*.

The *single CPU* refers to a *single core* nowadays, with its own cache. When you have multiple caches for multiple cores (physically in the same or separate cpu chips) they use some cache coherency protocol. In case of `MESI`, the core executing the atomic instruction will first ensure it has ownership of the cache line containing the operand and marks it `modified`, additionally locking it. If another core needs the cache line, it will do a read operation which the owner core will snoop and delay the answer until the atomic operation completes.

On single-cpu single-core systems, most instructions are atomic with respect to threading except for string instructions using a `REP` prefix because scheduling interrupts and thus context switches only happen on instruction boundaries. A hardware device could however observe non-atomic behaviour.

Comment: I did read section 8.1 before I posted. Ok so if you're saying MESI guarantees atomicity on multi-core, whats the need for the LOCK# signal and LOCK prefix??

Answer (score 9):

### Atomicity and Memory Ordering

For an operation to be atomic it must appear to be one undivided operation to any observer. That observer can be anything that can see the effect of the operation, whether its the thread does the operation, a different thread on the same processor a thread on different processor, or some component or device in the system. Observers that can't see the effect of the operation, whether the same thread, a different thread, or a device, don't affect whether the operation is atomic or not.

(Note that by processor I mean what Intel's documentation would call a logical processor. A system with two CPU sockets, each populated with a quad-core CPU with two logical processors per core would have a total of 16 processors.)

A related but different concept is memory ordering. Memory accesses are only sequentially consistent if they appear to an observer as happening in the order they occur in the program. This guarantee always applies then when the observer is the same thread as performed the operations. Other more limited guarantees of memory ordering are possible. A strong but not sequentially consistent ordering might guarantee many sorts of operations are ordered with respect to each other, but not all. A weak memory ordering provides no guarantees about how accesses appear to other threads.

### Compilers and Atomicity

When you're writing a program in C or some other higher level language it may appear that certain operations are atomic and sequentially ordered, but the compiler only generally guarantees this when viewed from the same thread that performed those operations. However, from the compiler's perspective any code that runs when a thread is asynchronously interrupted happens in different thread of execution even if that code runs in the same OS thread. That means the code running in a signal handler or in a structured exception handler isn't guaranteed to see operations performed outside the the handler in the same thread as being atomic or sequentially consistent.

Because of the limited general guarantee the compiler is free to do things like implement what look to be atomic operations using multiple assembler instructions make them appear non-atomic to other observers. The compiler can also reorder memory accesses, even remove apparently redundant accesses entirely. It can do whatever optimizations it wants so long in the single uninterrupted thread case the program still behaves as if it were doing all those operations in program order.

In the multi-threaded case, or where signal or exception handlers a present, it's necessary to take special steps to inform the compiler where you need it to provide broader guarantees of atomicity and memory ordering. That's the purpose special atomic types and functions. Even if the CPU guarantees every instruction is atomic and every memory access is sequentially consistent to all other threads, the compiler doesn't.

### Intel CPUs and Atomicity

Intel CPUs make it fairly easy for the compiler to provide these guarantees. Except for some odd cases, instructions are uninterruptable. Any event that causes the execution of an instruction to be interrupted either happens after the instruction is fully completed or allows the instruction to resumed as if it were never executed. The means that at the machine code level every operation is atomic and every memory operation is sequentially consistent as it appears to code running on the same processor. In the single processor case nothing needs to be done provide these guarantees except when they need to be to visible to devices other than the processor. In that case the `LOCK` prefix combined with uncached memory regions must be used to guarantee read/modify/write instructions are atomic and memory accesses appear sequentially consistent to other devices.

In the multi-processor case when accessing cached memory the cache coherency protocol provides guarantees of atomicity with most instructions and a strong memory ordering but not a sequentially consistent ordering. The exact mechanism by which is does this doesn't matter much, just the guarantees is gives. Any instruction that only accesses a single memory location will appear atomic to other processors. The ordering guarantees are too long to go into here, Intel uses 16 bullet points to describe them, but they apparently its a superset the guarantees that C and C++ provide with the acquire and release memory order. When that level of memory ordering is specified, the C/C++ atomic operations can use ordinary unlocked instructions.

The need for the `LOCK` prefix, and those instructions where the `LOCK` prefix is implicit, comes when you need stronger guarantees than the cache coherency protocol provides. If you need your read/modifiy/write instructions to be atomic you need to use the `LOCK` prefix. If you need sequentially consistent ordering you need to use the `LOCK` prefix.

The `LOCK` prefix is where the high cost of atomic operations comes from. It causes the processor to wait for all previous load and store operations to complete. Even though when accessing cached memory the `LOCK` prefix handled entirely within the cache without asserting LOCK#, the processor still needs to wait to ensure the operation appears sequentially consistent to other processors.

### Summary

So in summary the answers to your questions are:

1. The cache coherency protocol can only enforce atomicity of certain machine code instruction when viewed from other processors. It can't ensure that the compiler generates a single instruction for an operation you want to be atomic. It also can't guarantee that the instruction appears to be atomic to non-processor devices on the system.
2. The `LOCK` prefix is used on machine code instructions that

   - perform multiple memory accesses and need appear to be atomic to other processors
   - need to be sequentially consistent to other processors
   - need to be atomic and/or sequentially consistent to other non-processor devices.
3. When its possible to get the necessary atomicity and memory ordering guarantees without using the `LOCK` prefix, the instructions used are the same as ordinary instructions and so cost the same. Where `LOCK` prefix is needed to provide the necessary guarantees the cost of the instruction becomes much higher than a normal instruction.

Comment: so, why cache-coherency can't promise the sequential order of store ? any example ? thanks :)