# How is atomicity implemented by the CPU?

Tags: multithreading, x86, cpu, atomic, cpu-architecture

I have been told/read online the cache coherency protocol MESI/MESIF:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol

also enforces atomicity- for example for a lock. However, this really really doesn't make sense to me for the following reasons:

1) MESI manages cache access for **all** instructions. If MESI also enforces atomicity, how do we get race conditions? Surely all instructions would be atomic and we'd never get race conditions?

2) If MESI gurarantees atomicity, whats the point of the `LOCK` prefix?

3) Why do people say atomic instructions carry overhead- if they are implemented using the same cache coherency model as all other x86 instructions?

Generally-speaking could somebody please explain how the CPU implements locks at a low-level?

Comment: Didn't you just [ask this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25345440/596781)?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not exactly- I edited that question after the answers to refine my question. Now I gathered them all- I created this new question which is more focused.

Comment: Please don't do that. If your point is essentially the same but you simply failed to express it properly, *fix* the existing question. You can use bounties to attract future attention.

Comment: You seem to confuse visibility guarantees (no thread sees an old memory value, the responsibility of the cache coherency protocol) with making sure am instruction is executed atomically. `add [eax],  5` isn't executed as a single instruction in modern cpus but split up into several smaller micro ops

Comment: Voo, that is certainly possible. So if I call an "atomic" x86 instruction without the LOCK prefix, is this atomic because the CPU has special circuitry which ensures the instruction completes in one CPU cycle? Or does such an instruction still need cache coherency policy for atomicity? If its the former I understand, if its the latter I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @voo said, you are confusing coherency with atomicity.

Cache coherency covers many scenarios, but the basic example is when 2 different agents (cores on a multicore chip, processors on a multi-socket one, etc..), access the same line, they may both have it cached locally. MESI guarantees that when one of them writes a new value, all other stale copies are first invalidated, to prevent usage of the old value. As a by-product, this in fact guarantees atomicity of a *single* read or write access to memory, on a cacheline granularity, which is part of the CPU charter on x86 (and many other architectures as well). It does more than that - it's a crucial part of memory ordering and consistency guarantees that the CPU provides you.

It does not, however, provide any larger scale of atomicity, which is crucial for handling concepts like thread-safety and critical sections. What you are referring to with the locked operations is a read-modify-write flow, which is not guaranteed to be atomic by default (at least not on common CPUs), since it consists of 2 distinct accesses to memory. without a lock in place, the CPU may receive a snoop in between, and must respond according to the MESI protocol. The following scenario is perfectly legal for e.g.:

```
  core 0       |      core 1
---------------------------------
y = read [x]   |
increment y    |    store [x] <- z 
               |
store [x] <- y |
```

Meaning that your memory increment operation on core 0 didn't work as expected. If [x] holds a mutex for e.g, you may think it was free and that you managed to grab it, while core 1 already took it.

Having the read-modify-write operation on core 0 locked (and x86 provides many possible options, locked add/inc, locked compare-exchange, etc..), would stall the other cores until the operation is done, so it essentially enhances the inter-core protocol to allow rejecting snoops.

It should be noted that a simple MESI protocol, if used correctly with alternative guarantees (like fences), can provide lock-free methods to perform atomic operations.

Comment: Just to emphasise, I believe compare-exchange requires the LOCK prefix too (because its only XCHG which has automatic locking). Assuming I am correct, what is the purpose of CMPXCHG without the LOCK prefix, if its not atomic without?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, the "locked" was meant to apply for that one as well, i'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

The LOCK prefix has one purpose, that is taking a lock on that address followed by instructing MESI to flush that cache line on all other processors followed so that reading or writing that address by all other processors (or hardware devices!) blocks until the lock is released (which it is at the end of the instruction).

The LOCK prefix is slow (several hundred cycles) because it has to synchronize the bus for the duration and the bus speed and latency is much lower than CPU speed.

General operation of LOCK instruction

```
1. validate
2. establish address lock on cache line
3. wait for all processors to flush (MESI kicks in here)
4. perform operation within cache line
5. flush cache line to RAM (which releases the lock)
```

Disclaimer: Much of this comes from the documentation of the Pentium F00F bug (where the validate part was erroneously done after establish lock) and so might be out of date.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know answers to 1 and 3?

Comment: 3 is already answered. 1 cannot be addressed by any amount of hardware as it is subject to the Turing incompleteness theorem.

Comment: You seem to have concentrated your answer on the LOCK prefix. The whole point of my question is that I have read the LOCK prefix isn't necessary because MESI will guarantee atomicity. Therefore for Q3, I am not referring to any overhead regarding the LOCK prefix. If a non-atomic instruction and an atomic instruction are both processed using the MESI protocol, why would an atomic instruction be more expensive?

Comment: I don't see what Q1 has to do with turing? If MESI guarantees atomicity and all instructions "go through" MESI, how can we ever get a race condition if all instructions are atomic?

Comment: "all instructions are atomic" is not true across multiple CPUs even with MESI. An unlocked inc instruction can be split between the read and the write.

Comment: how does LOCK and cache-line enforce sequential consistency / total order ?

Comment: @Chinaxing: LOCK doesn't do that. MESI does. A write to a memory address invalidates the cache line containing that address on all other processors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that while the cache is involved in ordinary memory operations, it is required to do *more* for atomic operations than for your run of the mill ones.

---

Added later...

For ordinary operations:

- when writing to memory, your typical core/cpu will maintain a write
  queue, so that once the write has been dispatched, the core/cpu
  continues processing instructions, while some other mechanics deals
  with emptying the queue of pending writes -- negotiating with the
  cache as required.  On some processors the pending writes need not be
  written away in the order they were put into the queue.
- when reading from memory, if the required value is not immediately
  available, the core/cpu may continue processing instructions, while
  some other mechanics perform the required reads -- negotiating with
  the cache as required.

all of which is designed to allow the core/cpu to keep going, decoupled as far as possible from the truely ghastly business of accessing real memory, via layers of cache, which is all horribly *slow*.

Now, for your atomic operations, the state of the core/cpu has to be synchronised with the state of the cache/memory.

So, for a "release" store: (a) everything in the write queue must be completed, before (b) the "release" write itself is completed, before (c) normal processing can continue.  So all the benefits of the asynchronous writing of cache/memory may have to be foregone, until the atomic write completes.  Similarly, for an "acquire" load: any reads which come after the "acquire" read must be delayed.

As it happens, the x86 is remarkably "well behaved".  It does not reorder writes, so a "release" store does not need any extra work to ensure that it comes after any earlier stores.  On the read side it also does not need to do anything special for an "acquire".  If two or more cores/cpus are reading and writing the same piece of memory, then there will be more invalidating and reloading of cache lines, with the attendant overhead.  When doing a "sequentially consistent" store, it has to be followed by an explicit `mfence` operation, which will stall the cpu/core until all writes have been flushed from the write queue.  It is true that "sequentially consistent" is easier to think about... but for code where access to shared data is protected by locks, "acquire"/"release" is sufficient.

For your atomic "read-modify-write" and conditional versions thereof, the interaction with the cache/memory is even stronger.  The cpu/core executing the operation must not only synchronise itself with the state of cache/memory, it must also arrange for other cpus/cores which access the object of the atomic operation to stall until it is complete and has been written away (committed to cache/memory).  The impact of this will depend on whether there is any actual contention with other cpu(s)/core(s) at that moment.

Comment: I'm just trying to work out if its the atomic instructions which do the word, or the MESI protocol? It would make sense if its the atomic instructions because that explains higher latency and the whole point of the instructions existing.